# XPTable data passing between Two WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created two forms with `xptables`. When the button in form1 is clicked it displays form2. Where i'm performing some operations. After results will be stored in `xptable` of form2. When export button in form2 is clicked it should pass data of form2 `xptable` to form1 `xptable` and also saves in new text file. When i run my code the results are stored in text file but not in form1's `xptable`.

Edit : Calling form2 from form1:

```
private void but_form2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 tempForm = new Form2();
        this.AddOwnedForm(tempForm);
        tempForm.Show();
    }
```

Here is my coding for export from form2.

```
private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Save as txt (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files(*.*)|";
        sfd.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
        sfd.ShowDialog();
        try
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(sfd.FileName,
                FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                FileAccess.Write));
            Form1 obj = new Form1();
            foreach (Row r in tblProxiesLive.Rows)
            {
                obj.loadsecondtable(r.Cells[1].Text);
                sw.Write(r.Cells[1].Text + "\r\n");



            }
            sw.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            string xp = x.ToString();
        }
        Form2 h = new Form2();
        h.Hide();
        h.Close();
    }
```

. And in form1 coding :

```
public void loadsecondtable(string s)
    {

        int snumber = this.tabproxmodel.Rows.Count + 1;
        Row r = new Row();
        r.Cells.Add(new Cell(snumber, Color.DarkBlue, Color.FromArgb(234, 215, 184), f2));
        r.Cells.Add(new Cell(s, Color.FromArgb(225, 175, 91), Color.White, f2));
        r.Cells.Add(new Cell("", (Image)new Bitmap(10, 10), Color.YellowGreen, Color.White, f2));
        r.Cells.Add(new Cell("", (Image)new Bitmap(10, 10)));
        r.Cells.Add(new Cell("", (Image)new Bitmap(10, 10)));
        r.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(6, 92, 155);
        this.tabproxmodel.Rows.Add(r);                                            
    }
```

can anyone help me in this ? What should i need to change ?

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Form2 h = new Form2();
        h.Hide();
        h.Close(); <--- whats this doing here? You should give more information about how to open form2 in form1.

Comment: @kavithai_kannan Can you please explain what's an xptable ?.

Comment: @AviralSingh Here is the link to know about xptable : http://sourceforge.net/projects/xptable/ , http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11596/XPTable-NET-ListView-meets-Java-s-JTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I've found answer for this friends .

- Have to change the xptable modifier as from private to public 
  and the coding for form2 follows :

  ```
     Form f = Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
      for (int df = 0; df < tblmodelform2.Rows.Count; df++)
      {

              int sNumber = ((Form1)f).tabmodelform1.Rows.Count;
              Row r = new Row();
              //int ss = int.Parse(s);
              r.Cells.Add(new Cell(sNumber, Color.DarkBlue, Color.FromArgb(234, 215, 184), f2));
              r.Cells.Add(new Cell(tblProxies22[df,1].Text, Color.FromArgb(225, 175, 91), Color.White, f2));
              // r.Cells.Add(new Cell(pa, Color.FromArgb(225, 175, 91), Color.White, f2));
              r.Cells.Add(new Cell("", (Image)new Bitmap(10, 10), Color.YellowGreen, Color.White, f2));
              r.Cells.Add(new Cell("", (Image)new Bitmap(10, 10), Color.YellowGreen, Color.White, f2));
              r.Cells.Add(new Cell("", (Image)new Bitmap(10, 10)));
              //   r.Cells.Add(new Cell("", (Image)new Bitmap(10, 10)));
              if (!IsHandleCreated)
              {
                  this.CreateControl();
                  ((Form1)f).tabmodelform1.Rows.Add(r);
              }
              else
              {
                  this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                  {
                      ((Form1)f).tabmodelform1.Rows.Add(r);
                  }));
              }

      }
  ```

This Solution will be applicable for all the controls not only xptable. We can pass listbox,datagridview items from form to form using this one.
Thanks for everyone ..!

Answer (score 1):

In `btnExport_Click` method instead create new `Form1` object you should to use existing one.

Good solution is to use `events`.
Easy solution is to pass `Form1` as parameter to `Form2`. Code:

add to `Form2` class:

```
 Form1 pointerToForm1;
 public Form2(Form1 pointerToForm1) {
      this.pointerToForm1 = pointerToForm1ł
 }
```

In `Form1` change method:

```
private void but_form2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 tempForm = new Form2(this);
    this.AddOwnedForm(tempForm);
    tempForm.Show();
}
```

In `Form2` change method:

```
private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (...)
        //Form1 obj = new Form1();
        Form1 obj = pointerToForm1;
        foreach (Row r in tblProxiesLive.Rows)
        {
            obj.loadsecondtable(r.Cells[1].Text);
            sw.Write(r.Cells[1].Text + "\r\n");
        }
    (...)
}
```